# javac: file not found in Ubuntu Java

Tags: java, bash, shell, ubuntu

Getting errors in Ubuntu while running command **./run1.sh**

```
javac: file not found: edge.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
Error: Could not find or load main class median_degree
```

In run1.sh file

```
javac -cp .:libs/java-json.jar:./src edge.java ./src median_degree.java
java -cp .:libs/java-json.jar:./src median_degree
```

File Structure

[image: for java class]

[image]

Can anyone help on how to write script file for this? I have tried lots options but none of them is working. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
javac -cp .:libs/java-json.jar ./src/edge.java ./src/median_degree.java
```

as the source files are not part of the class path and needs to be supplied as source files using the full path.

Comment: I have tried your command, it was giving error - javac: file not found: edge.java

Comment: OK, so can you perform `ls src`? I presume you are on unix because of the colon (:) in the class path.

Comment: ls src working fine. One more update, I have made mistake to execute  your code. After correcting it, the above error is gone. But Now error is-  javac: invalid flag: ./src/median_degree.java

Comment: I've executed above command without issue; note that classes will be put in the `src` folder which you may want to include in the classpath.

Comment: The problem with script file itself. I have created new script file with same commands and it's working fine. Thank you for your suggestion.